# $\sqrt{(c+d-2)^2 + a^2} + \sqrt{(c+d-2)^2 + b^2} \ge \sqrt{b^2+c^2} + \sqrt{a^2+d^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b \ge 2$ and $c,d \ge 3$ be integers, then the following inequality holds true:

$$\sqrt{(c+d-2)^2 + a^2} + \sqrt{(c+d-2)^2 + b^2} \ge \sqrt{b^2+c^2} + \sqrt{a^2+d^2} + \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}.$$

I tried to prove the inequality by squaring but not able to control after that.

I have also verified for small values and it seems true.

Can someone help how to proceed proving it?

Comment: This must use one of those tricks in the book "Inequalities" by Springer...

Comment: I suspect the first step is to substitute $c=c+1, d=d+1$ to get rid of the 2, and have $a,b,c,d \geq 2$ and then a contest problem...

Comment: How about $a = b = c = d = 3$, $LHS = 10 < RHS = 3\sqrt{18}$?

Answer (score 2):

The inequality you are trying to prove is wrong :

you can put :

a = 3  and  b = 3 and c = 3 and d=3

Substituting, we find :

$$ 10 > 3\sqrt{18} $$
This is a mistake

Next time try to ask the right questions